# Detect collision between two objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Collision detection is pretty simple in Swift - yet on this particular project, body collision is not triggering the `didBeginContact` event as usual.

Here is my checklist for two bodies colliding (using soldiers and bullets):

1. Add `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to the class.
2. set the physicsWorld appropriately, usually:  `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self`
3. Create categories for each group of nodes you will have. E.g. `let bulletCategory = 0x1 << 0`
4. Create SKNodes for each bullet and soldier.
5. Give each bullet and soldier a physics body with a matching shape.
6. Set each bullet's categoryBitMask to the `bulletCategory` (soldiers are set to soldierCategory).
7. Set each bullet's contactBitMask to the `soldierCategory` (soldiers are set to bulletCategory).
8. Define `didBeginContact()` handler.

Below is my complete code. It is a minimal ~20 line "Hello World" for collision.

If you create a new "Game" and copy paste this into the GameScene.swift, it will run, just no collision events will be fired.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var soldier = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)

    let soldierCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0;
    let bulletCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1;

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        // THE soldier
        soldier.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
        soldier.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 40)
        soldier.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        soldier.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        soldier.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = soldierCategory
        soldier.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = bulletCategory
        soldier.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0


        // bulletS
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("makeBullet"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.addChild(soldier)
    }

    func makeBullet() {
        var bullet = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: self.frame.height, width: 10, height: 40), cornerRadius: CGFloat(0))
        bullet.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()

        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 40))
        bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bulletCategory
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = soldierCategory
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = soldierCategory

        var movebullet = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: CGFloat(-400), duration: 1)
        var movebulletForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(movebullet)
        bullet.runAction(movebulletForever)

        self.addChild(bullet)
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("CONTACT")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait a second. If a physicsBody is not "dynamic" can it not collide with anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few items missing from your checklist:

1. One of the physics bodies must be dynamic
2. <del>The physics bodies must be moved by a force/impulse or by setting their velocities</del>
3. The positions of the physics bodies should match their corresponding sprite/shape nodes

<del>For (2), you are moving each bullet by changing its position over time with an `SKAction`.</del>

For (3), the position of each bullet starts at (0, 0), while the shape is drawn at the top-center of the scene. Since the physics body is centered at the shape node's position, there is a mismatch between the locations of the shape and the physics body; the bullet's physics body never makes contact with the soldier. To resolve this, try

```
    var bullet = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(10, 40))
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0, self.size.height)
```

Also, the physics body of the soldier is half the radius of its shape.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. Is there a way where I can debug or see the positions of the physics bodies? I want to see how they are moving / set differently than the objects, but I can't color them in.

Comment: Set `view.showsPhysics = true` in `didMoveToView` or in your view controller.

Comment: Do both physicsbodies need to be dynamic? 

In another project, I made a clone of FlappyBirdy, and only one object is dynamic (the bird), while the pipes are not dynamic, and just moved using `SKAction.moveByX()`, the contact event still occurs

Comment: I suggest you use a `performSelector` `SKAction` to call `makeBullet` instead of using a `NSTimer`. Actions pause/resume appropriately when you pause the game (with `view.paused = true`) and are removed automatically when you transition scenes.

Comment: So right now when a bullet collides with a soldier, it will push the soldier. Do you know how to make them trigger a collision, but continue through eachother?

Comment: You can set `bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0` to prevent the bullet from colliding with anything, or you can set `bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~soldierCategory` to prevent the bullet from colliding with the soldier only. By default, all bits are set so it will collide with all categories.